# WPF window with 2 grid and using rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I tried to do the following: I have a WPF Window with 2 grid. The outer grid is my login grid,the inner contains my combobox. I wrote a code when the program check if the following person is an admin or not. If not,simply open a new window,if admin,a combobox appears and you can choose between combobox values,so the program drops u the common window,which one you choose.

```
<Grid Name="Grid1">
 ---Textboxes and Buttons for my Login---
<Grid Name="Grid2" Visibility="Hidden">
<Canvas Name="CanvaS" Width="200" Height="90">
<ComboBox Width="180" Height="30" Name="CBBox">
<ComboBoxItem Name="Item1">Item1 Instruction
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Name="Item2">Item2 Instruction
                </ComboBoxItem>
<Button Name="Window" Click="Window_Click"/>

</Canvas Width="200"  Height="90">

    </Grid>


</Grid>
```

So I want the following: If I log in and the user is an admin,which is already checked,my main grid fades (tried it with rectangle,but didnt work for me) OR all the buttons are disabled and the Canvas is popping up,which is inside Grid 2. The only problem is,If i set Grid1 to Hidden,the whole window set to hidden,even Grid2,if I set Grid 1 to IsEnabled="False", can't click on Grid 2 neither. So how can I solve this? Or where should I use the rectangle in my code and with what Opacity?
 Everything else is working on my code,I only can't solve this problem, that's why I only show this part of my code.

Comment: You really need to read more about Layouts in WPF. If the outer grid is hidden/disabled, ofcourse the inner grid is also going to be hidden/disabled. You can try creating one more grid/stackpanel and put these 2 grids inside it rather than keeping grid2 inside grid1. That way hiding/disabling one wont affect other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all there were some problem in the code you have provided, I don't think this code was working for you as there were few closing tags were missing/inappropriate.

The problem is that you have added your Grid2 as a child within grid1. So all the operations performed for Grid1 will automatically affect Grid2. You will need to take Grid2 out of Grid1.

See below.

```
      <Grid Name="MainGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Name="Grid1" Grid.Row="0">
            </Grid>
            <Grid Name="Grid2" Visibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="1">
                <Canvas Name="CanvaS" Width="200" Height="90">
                    <ComboBox Width="180" Height="30" Name="CBBox">
                        <ComboBoxItem Name="Item1">Item1 Instruction
                        </ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem Name="Item2">Item2 Instruction
                        </ComboBoxItem>
                        <Button Name="Window" Click="Window_Click"/>
                    </ComboBox>
                </Canvas>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take your `Grid2` out of the `Grid1` because you can not have enabled `child control` inside disabled `parent`

Comment: Thank you all of you help! Solved! :)